# Remove obsolete packages after upgrading to 17.04?

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

I just upgraded my Kubuntu to 17.04 from 16.10 - following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ZestyUpgrades/Kubuntu).

But during the upgrade stage it was interrupted - my machine hung so I had to restart it.

So I missed the step of **Remove obsolete packages**.

After logging in, from my terminal:

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:        17.04
Codename:       zesty
```

I have it upgraded but how can I remove obsolete packages then?

**Edit:**

I did this:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

But is it the right way doing it?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get autoremove`?

Comment: @yolo7398 yes i did. is it the right way?

Comment: New version: `sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: Check out the question posted by Yaron above. Its much more comprehensive

Comment: @yolo7398 seen that answer. but which answer should i use? the accepted answer?